# How to read special characters from input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my form I have a few number input fields. Normally there is only one digit allowed. After that one digit has been put in, onKeyUp the next input field is selected. However for the cases where more than one digit are required I want to use `'*'` as an indicator. So when the users types *23 it won't skip.

I have come that far, however when I get the value of the input field I receive an empty string.

I want to remove the asterisk from the input. When I try to alter the input of the field in the keydown event, where multi is set to true, the input field value is not altered.

Altering the input type does fix the problem with the value being `""`, but then the step isn't functional any more.

I feel like I'm making a giant pile of code for something I feel should be fairly simple.

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="0" value="0">

var multi = 0;
// Keys to be ignored by the keyup event of .singleDigit.
var ignoreKeys = [ [8,46], [65,93], [107,222] ];
// Don't accept tab button, will skip an extra input field.
// Don't skip to next input, if input starts with *
// DOn't accept function buttons
$(".singleDigit").on('keyup', function(e){
  if(multi == 0
    && $.isNumeric($(this).val()) 
    && (e.which < ignoreKeys[0][0] || e.which > ignoreKeys[0][1])
    && (e.which < ignoreKeys[1][0] || e.which > ignoreKeys[1][1])
    && e.which < ignoreKeys[2][0]) {
    var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find('.input');
    inputs.eq( inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
  }
});
// on focus out reset multi boolean.
$(".singleDigit").on('focusout', function() {
  multi = 0;
});
// check for key combination of *
var lastKey = null;
$(".singleDigit").on('keydown', function(e){
  if(lastKey != null) {
    if(lastKey == 16 && e.which == 56) {
      multi = 1;
    }
  }
  if(e.which != null) {
    lastKey = e.which;
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do not you use input type text and have an additional check for number?

Comment: The input has a step functionality which only works on the number type. A + and - button was a requirement. Although it is seems more and more worth it to just write that instead of this whole mess.

Comment: yeah that's what I would suggest you to do. Have an extra function to check for the number and you can avoid all that mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it. Since I have the event, I can just prevent the default action.

```
var lastKey = null;
$(".singleDigit").on('keydown', function(e){
  if(lastKey != null) {
    if(lastKey == 16 && e.which == 56) {
      multi = 1;
      e.preventDefault();
    } 
  }
  if(e.which != null) {
    lastKey = e.which;
  }
});
```